# gksudo and logname issues

Tags: java, sudo, gksudo

We have a Java Swing cross platform application,which we are packaging into a deb file and installing it in the user's system. This application, upon it's start-up checks for the new version and installs it, if it finds any. At present for installing the new version, we are calling  `sudo dpkg -i XXX.deb` " in a gnome-terminal from java using `Runtime.exec()`.

I have tried to modify the `sudo` to `gksudo`, so there wont be need to open the gnome terminal to enter the user's password. The problem I am facing now is the installation script is not working properly by doing so, it is saying it cannot find `logname`(i.e current user's username, so that we can cleanup old files and install new ones in his home directory) , but when I do the same with `sudo` I am not getting any error. They wont let me change the script, as it is not big enhancement, but I am asking this out of curiosity why different behavior is observed with `sudo` and `gksudo`